# Reading data from LocalStorage in a Webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am using webview in my application, I have successfully written data on local storage, but I want to read some other data from it. Here is the code

```
private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            String key = "key";
            String value = "value";
            String loc;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                webView.evaluateJavascript("localStorage.setItem('" + key + "', '" + value + "');", null);
                webView.evaluateJavascript("localStorage.getItem('" + key + "');", null);
            }
            else {
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:localStorage.setItem('" + key + "', '" + value + "');");
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:localStorage.getItem('" + key + "');");
            }
        }

        /*@Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            String key = "key";
            String value = "value";
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                webView.evaluateJavascript("localStorage.setItem('" + key + "', '" + value + "');", null);
            }
            else {
                webView.loadUrl("javascript:localStorage.setItem('" + key + "', '" + value + "');");
            }
        }*/
    });
    webView.loadUrl(<some_website>);
}
```

Is there any way I can use `evaluateJavascript` function to read the value? Or any other way...

Comment: `localStorage.getItem(..)`?

Comment: `evaluateJavascript` doesn't return. So how to access the value returned by `localStorage.getItem()` ?

Comment: Use JavascriptInterface for that